# Transferring files via camera

Tags: algorithm, graphics, encoding, camera, signal-processing

Suppose that we have two computers, and want to send files from one to the other. Wired network, wireless network or any storage devices are not allowed. We can only use monitors and **pc** cameras. What is the fastest way to transfer files? Any practical ideas are welcome.

Comment: Isn't this kind of subverting the obvious policy they've got in place? And if you're talking about a camera (as opposed to a webcam), that **is** a storage device.

Comment: @kmort What I mean is a pc camera. I think it is interesting, isn't it?

Comment: Simplest/easiest might be to display a sequence of large QR codes on the screen of the transmitting PC and decode these via the webcam on the receiving PC. Data rate would not be very high though.

Answer (score 1):

Cool idea. This is exactly what QR codes do… So in theory, you could encode a whole file using many QR codes then display them in sequence while recording on the other side. 3kb 30x per second if assuming the reader can identify and decode at 30hz, so, 90kb per second? Add in checksums and a repeat of the data a few times to cater for errors (imagine a fly passes the screen), and you can probably safely transfer 20kb per second. Distance will depend on resolution of screen and camera and size of QR code, but with an optical zoom on the camera the distance could be quite a bit.

Would be a very fun school project…

Comment: Seems like someone did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721347/2631300

Answer (score 0):

To maximize distance, I would:
switch the hole monitor between black and while for coding the data (or if other colors can e better separated by the camera-chips use these ones).

The distance will depend on a lot of attributes such as:

- the optical system of your cameras  (fokus zoom...)
- the light around the monitor
- the brightness of your monitor
- resolution of your camera
- light sensitivity of your camera
- ...

The baud depend on how many bits you can encode simultaneous on a screen and the refresh rate of the screen.

The number of bits encoded simultaneous on a screen depend on:

- how many colors you use (how many can be distinguish by your camera over the given distance)
- how many areas for encoding you choose per line and number of rows
- how many bits you use for error checking / correction

Comment: For a 60 Hz refresh rate the data rate will probably be 30 bps at most, so it might take a while to transfer a file like this.

Comment: @Paul R: That is right but encoding more bits at once will reduce the possible distance. And the question was about maximal possible distance. It is always a trade of between transmission-rate and achievable distance.

Comment: Well the question is actually: "What is the fastest way to transfer files?" so I would guess the trade-off needs to be more towards a higher data rate and a shorter distance. 30 bps is slower than the old electromechanical teletypes of yesterday, so OK for short text messages but a bit impractical for file transfer.

Comment: Than encode as much bits per screen as possible (also using different colors for encoding more bits at once). Do not forget to add a kind of checksum to ensure that the data were transmitted correctly.